# SQL Server 2005 -Seeing SPs executing inside SPs

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-profiler

I am wondering if it is possible to see stored procs that are being executed by other stored procs in Sql Server Profiler, is it possible, and if so how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you profile using the SP::Starting event, you can see all the stored procedures that are executed. You want to make sure to get a couple of the profile columns included:

NestLevel - This shows the nesting level of SPs calling each other - so if Test calls EmbeddedTest then the SP::Starting event for Test wil show NestLevel=1 and the event for EmbeddedTest will show NestLevel=2

ObjectName - This shows the name of the stored procedure being executed

SPID - Session ID for the connection

So to find a calling sequence you need to look for an event with NestLevel greater then 1 and then look for the NestLevel=1 on the same SPID that preceeded the call. Of course this works for deeper nesting levels as well.